# How to display messages in a batch file when piping output?

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, cmd

I use a batch file below to concatenate video files using avidemux's cli executable.  The reason why I pipe most of avidemux's output into 00_log.log is that its output is highly verbose and shoveling this to a text file appears to leave behind more helpful status or critical error messages displayed on the console.  However, I'd like to see what file avidemux is working on at the time any error message pops up.  Below, everything following ECHO is not displayed in the console.

Commenting or removing `@echo off` simply relays the ECHO lines below at the beginning of the batch job rather than alongside avidemux's console output, thus limiting its use.

```
@echo off
>00_log.log (
ECHO Joining foo.mp4
"C:\Program Files\Avidemux\avidemux_cli.exe" --load 1.mp4 --append 2.mp4 --output-format MP4v2 --save D:\foo.mp4
ECHO Joining foo2.mp4
"C:\Program Files\Avidemux\avidemux_cli.exe" --load 3.mp4 --append 4.mp4 --output-format MP4v2 --save D:\foo2.mp4
)
ECHO Job Done
@Pause
```

Comment: `echo This always goes to the console  > CON`

Comment: Your code is not complete, there is a closing parenthesis missing...

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo.  The closing parenthesis is there in the batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply redirect the avidemux_cli output to the log file, but not the rest.
So, use something like:

```
@echo off
ECHO Joining foo.mp4
"C:\Program Files\Avidemux\avidemux_cli.exe" --load 1.mp4 --append 2.mp4 --output-format MP4v2 --save D:\foo.mp4 >> 00_log.log 
ECHO Joining foo2.mp4
"C:\Program Files\Avidemux\avidemux_cli.exe" --load 3.mp4 --append 4.mp4 --output-format MP4v2 --save D:\foo2.mp4 >> 00_log.log 
ECHO Job Done
@Pause
```